# Server side event is not working Kubernetes ingress controller and erred out

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress

We have an API which will create a cluster and wait for the status until it creates and executes a query in database.

We tried this through *Ingress* and are getting timed-out.

And we have set in ingress rule as below:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
```

Error:

> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"

If we set this it's creating under `/data` path which is our main API path, and it's not working as expected.

Is there any direct annotation to use server side events?

If we use the above snippet in ingress rule and get this error in controller logs.

Below error Error:

> ```sh
> exit status 1
> 2020/06/26 04:57:22 [emerg] 132#132: location "/" is outside location "/data/" in /tmp/nginx-cfg140739857:11409
> nginx: [emerg] location "/" is outside location "/data/" in /tmp/nginx-cfg140739857:11409
> nginx: configuration file /tmp/nginx-cfg140739857 test failed.
> ```

Comment: Could you share your Ingress YAMLs config? ITs local envo or cloud? What K8s version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As the [doc](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#not-using-standard-document-root-locations) suggests, you should never use `/` for hosting your data from. It should be somewhere in `/data/*`.

> Some directories in any file system should never be used for hosting data from. These include `/` and `root`. You should never use these as your document root.
> Doing this leaves you open to a request outside of your expected area returning private data.

NEVER DO THIS!!!

```
server {
    root /;

    location / {
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Ingress controller which we are using 0.17.1 , and is there any direct annotation for this? or else is there any otherway we can acheive this.